# Kegerator taps stick when inactive

Tags: cleaning, kegerator

So I've noticed with my kegerator, if I don't pour a beer for a few days, the taps can get very sticky.  So sticky sometimes that it actually takes a scary amount of force to pull the tap open to start to dispense beer.  My taps are pretty standard ones that came with my tower, something like this:

[image]

Is there any kind of special grease I can buy or precautions I can follow as to keep my taps from getting stuck after a few days of no use?

Comment: Are you running home brew through them? Or are you buying kegs?

Comment: I'm running homebrew through them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with this kind of faucet is that the seal is at the rear of the assembly (see **10** below).

[image]

After dispensing, everything post-seal (pretty much all of **9**, parts of **6**, and the inside of the tap body) will be coated in beer. Being open to the air this will soon dry out and gum up the works.

Best solution is to flush out the inside of the tap with water or no-rinse sanitizer after using it, to rinse away the beer. Just get a nice strong spray bottle, or anything capable of jetting some water up in there. It would be good to do this every time, but especially if you know it won't be used for a while.

If that doesn't work, pick up some [food-grade lubricant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007QU2UAA) and *lightly* coat the moving parts.

Failing everything, you can upgrade to a modern [front-sealing tap](http://www.chicompany.net/images/Repair%20Parts%20-%20Perlick%20SS.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was talking with another homebrewing friend this evening.  Apparently there are also more expensive (but possibly worth it) taps that don't have this problem as well.  I think for now the food-grade lubricant may be my solution.

Comment: There's also something called keg lube you can use. Most homebrew suppliers should have it.